Show that there is at least eight square matrices $X$ such that $X^2+AX=B$
I need to show that there exist at least eight solutions for:
$$
X^2 + AX = B
$$
As well as find one of them, given:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 & -1 & 7 \\
-3 & 1 & 5 \\
-3 & -1 & 7
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
6 & 5 & -13 \\
4 & 8 & -14 \\
4 & 5 & -11
\end{bmatrix}$$
I tried creating a $3 \times 3$ matrix for $X$ and calculating $X^2 + AX -B= 0$, as well as assuming $X=A+C$, $C$ being a matrix to be determined later. But I couldn't proceed further. Anyone have any suggestions?

Hint: try to solve it like you would solve a normal quadratic equation.
Solution:
The equation $x^2 + ax - b = 0$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ has solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ given by the quadratic formula:
$$
x = \frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2 + 4b}}{2}.
$$
Coming back to our matrix equation, we want to find solutions in the same way. To do so, we need to be able to calculate $\sqrt{A^2 + 4B}$, and we need that $A$ commutes with $\sqrt{A^2 + 4B}$. If $A^2 + 4B$ is diagonalizable, say $M D M^{-1} = A^2 + 4B$, then we can take $\sqrt{A^2 + 4B} = M D^{\frac{1}{2}} M^{-1}$, where $D^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is obtained by choosing square roots for the diagonal entries of $D$. If $A$ commutes with $\sqrt{A^2 + 4B}$, then it also commutes with $A^2 + 4B$ and thus with $B$. Conversely, if $AB = BA$ then $A$ commutes with $A^2 + 4B$ and hence with $\sqrt{A^2 + 4B}$
(see Commutativity of the square root of matrices ).
If $A^2 + 4B$ has distinct eigenvalues, then it is diagonalizable and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the 3 distinct eigenvalues. We then have $2^3 = 8$ choices for $D^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (if the eigenvalues are non-zero), giving us 8 solutions. Other solutions could possibly exist.
It thus remains to calculate the eigenvalues of $A^2 + 4B$, and to check that $AB = BA$. Using sympy I got the eigenvalues $1,8$ and $16$, and verified that $AB = BA$, so that we find 8 solutions using the method described above.

Here is a direct solution. Denote the entries of $X$ by $x_1,\ldots ,x_9$, and write down the nine equations in these variables induced by $X^2+AX=B$ for the two given matrices. They are very easy, and $7$ variables are immediately determined (in my case all except for $x_5$ and $x_9$), and the remaining equations give exactly four solutions for
$x_5$, namely $x_5=3,4,-4,-5$, and a quadratic equation in $x_9$. This yields exactly eight solutions. For $x_5=-5$ we have $x_9^2=2$, for $x_5=-4$ we have $x_9^2 + 6x_9 + 7=0$, for $x_5=3$ we have $x_9^2 + 8x_9 + 14=0$, and so on. For example, $X$ is given as follows for $x_5=-5$ and $x_9^2=2$:
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix} 1-2x_9 & -2 & 2x_9 \cr 1-x_9 & -5 & x_9+3 \cr 1-x_9 & -2 & x_9 \end{pmatrix}
$$
